# How to create multiple setters

Tags: flutter, setter

I have a variable which I want to give the option to call the setter with multiple types, but I would set the variable with one type of course. For example, if I have a variable called list, I want to be able to call the setter using a single list item i.e. a string and then in the setter method I would add the string to the end of the list. Another way to set the variable would be through an actual list, and the setter, I would just set the list to the list passed in.

Here's an example of what I would like to do, but the second time I call the list setter method, I get an error saying `The name 'list' is already defined`:

```
List<String> _list = [];

List<String> get list => list;

set list(List<String> newList) {
  _list = newList;
}

set list(String newListItem) {
  _list = [..._list, newListItem];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Remi mentioned, it is not possible to do so. I would argue that it would be best not to do so because it changes the expectation of the contract of the setter. That is, you expect a setter to replace the value of a variable. Having a setter that appends to it is counter-intuitive and will lead to confusion for other developers.

Generally, for the maintainability of a code base, it's better to have an explicit interface to your class's behavior than to provide terse shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

In Dart you can have only one setter per variable.
You will need to rename one of your setters to use a different name.